# GNOME Tweaks shows only general

Tags: bug-reporting

A week ago, I installed Ubuntu, and I wanted to make it to look better, so I installed GNOME Tweaks and all it shows me is the general tab.

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-tweaks
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Yet it still doesn't seem to work normally and it continues showing only the general tab.
My Ubuntu version is 20.04 and here's what the problem looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, you haven't posted any screenshots, but from what I can tell here
The window is just not streched enough.
[image: Only the general section]

So you just grab the window border, and pull it until it looks like this
[image: The entire thing :D]

and there ya go! fixed!
You should also post screenshots when you ask questions.

Comment: hi posted a screenshot

Comment: did my reply solve your problem? if it did then you should check it as the answer

Comment: no, srry i don`t see that icon

Comment: its right under the down vote button, it looks like a gray check mark

Comment: look at the other question and look at the ss

Comment: @Sergiu So did you grab down the window and grab the edges and expand the window on the left hand side until the screen shows the left hand pane? According to your screenshot, you have not adjusted the size of the window yet (you haven't followed these instructions).

Comment: Ok i will try soon if its works i will contact u

Comment: thx @mchid sorry for being that dumb :)